# Connecting android studio to Oracle Cloud

Tags: java, oracle, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I'm trying to make a form in Android Studio where the data will be stored in Oracle Cloud Database. Is this possible using jdbc or do i really need to install Oracle Database first

[I have tried using tips from](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=34cl0Z9qVYM&t=847s) but it's not working for Oracle cloud

Comment: what does the documentation of Oracle Cloud Database say about this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are connecting to Oracle Autonomous Database then use the [quickstart with ADB](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/getting-started-using-jdbc.html) as a reference and follow all steps.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with connection android app with jetpack compose to oracle autonomous database. Dependencies are set correctly, because my viemodel normally load data from oracle cloud, but in @composable function i get error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/sql/DriverAction;
at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:454)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:379)
at com.msm.msmtodo.model.OracleDatabase$Companion.getConnection(OracleDatabase.kt:14)
at com.msm.msmtodo.viewmodel.TodoViewModel.getData(TodoViewModel.kt:20)
at com.msm.msmtodo.viewmodel.TodoViewModel.loadDataState(TodoViewModel.kt:59)
at com.msm.msmtodo.MainActivityKt$ToDoItem$1$1.invoke(MainActivity.kt:108)
at com.msm.msmtodo.MainActivityKt$ToDoItem$1$1.invoke(MainActivity.kt:108)
at androidx.compose.foundation.ClickableKt$clickable$4$gesture$1$1$2.invoke-k-4lQ0M(Clickable.kt:167)
at androidx.compose.foundation.ClickableKt$clickable$4$gesture$1$1$2.invoke(Clickable.kt:156)
at androidx.compose.foundation.gestures.TapGestureDetectorKt$detectTapAndPress$2$1.invokeSuspend(TapGestureDetector.kt:255)
at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTaskKt.resume(DispatchedTask.kt:178)
at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTaskKt.dispatch(DispatchedTask.kt:166)
at kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.dispatchResume(C
```